# Wrapper.vm is empty in vue test and defineExpose does not resolve it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vue-test-utils, vitest

I am re-writing some unit tests for a Vue component since we made the swap to the `script setup` tag recently. However, when I try to access a computed property via `wrapper.vm`, the object returns as empty and the property is undefined.

The test previously worked without `script setup` when it was written like this:

```js
it('Check that the axis spacing options are set up correctly for less than 20 results', () => {
    wrapper.vm.isScreenLg = true
    expect(wrapper.vm.hAxisLabelSpacing).toBe(0)

    wrapper.vm.isScreenLg = false
    expect(wrapper.vm.hAxisLabelSpacing).toBe(4)
})
```

However, I can't access `isScreenLg` via wrapper.vm anymore to be able to set it to true and test the computed value.

In lieu of this, I've triggered the `resize` event within my test - but I still can't get to the `wrapper.vm.hAxisLabelSpacing` computed property in order to test that the it has been set correctly:

```js
it('Check that the axis spacing options are set up correctly for less than 20 shareprice results', async () => {
    global.innerWidth = 1440
    // Trigger the window resize event.
    global.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
    await nextTick()
    await nextTick()

    expect(wrapper.vm.hAxisLabelSpacing).toBe(0)
})
```

Lastly, I have tried returning `hAxisLabelSpacing` via the `defineExpose` macro but that seemingly had no impact. I'm truly at a loss and any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Addendum:* Just in case it has any bearing, in this test, I'm creating a TestComponent  so that I can wrap the whole component in the `Suspense` tag (see below). This removes a warning we were seeing about not having a Suspense tag for an asynchronous component, but means I'm creating a wrapper with this TestComponent rather than the imported Vue component.

```js
// Test component created
const TestComponent = defineComponent({
  components: { Suspense, SharepriceGraph },
  template: '<Suspense><SharepriceGraph /></Suspense>'
})

// Full mounted component created with the TestComponent object
const wrapper = createFullWrapper(TestComponent)
```

Comment: "Lastly, I have tried returning hAxisLabelSpacing via the defineExpose macro" - this is the correct way to do this.  "Just in case it has any bearing, in this test, I'm creating a TestComponent" - this is most likely the case. Why is it so? Is SharepriceGraph async? Then the problem is that you don't wait for it to be created. Is SharepriceGraph supposed to be vm? Then it's wrong because it was wrapped, try to use  ref to get an instance

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem, there are detached pieces of code with some relevant parts missing, that's not constructive when you expect other users to find what's wrong with the case because they are unaware of it

Comment: can you try `wrapper.findComponent({ name: 'SharepriceGraph' }).vm` instead of `wrapper.vm` and tell us more?

Comment: @AliBahrami you gem! So if I use your technique, I finally get a value from it - the wrong one, so my test was still failing at first haha - but it's more than I had managed before. I'm was able to then tinker with it and get my tests to pass :D
Any idea as to why it needs to be done this way? Or just sheer genius?